Why are unequipped hands "bare" but unequipped eyes "naked"?
We use "naked eye" to refer to eyes used without any equipment, but "bare hands" to describe hands or feet used without any equipment.
How did these terms come to be this way? Why don't we say "naked-handed" or "bare-eyed"?
As a bonus, here's a Google Ngram chart of their usage: 

Could you explain why you think consistency in expressions of this kind is necessary or even likely?

It falls down to Semantic nuances.
"Bare hands" refers to hands without any covering or tools. The word "bare" in this context emphasizes the lack of protection or equipment. This usage has become idiomatic, particularly in phrases like "with one's bare hands".
similar example:
Bare feet describes feet without shoes, focusing on their exposed, natural state.
Bare minimum means the simplest or least amount necessary.
"Naked eye," on the other hand, is a specific phrase used to describe unaided vision without optical instruments like telescope or binoculers. The term "naked" here emphasizes the direct, unassisted nature of the observation. This phrase likely originated in scientific contexts, where distinguishing between aided and unaided vision was crucial.
other usages:
Naked truth to mean the raw, unembellished truth, focusing on its exposed and raw nature.
Naked ambition to describe ambition laid bare, often implying it is unhidden or unfiltered.

I agree completely, but 'Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.' (Ex Community Bot)

Please be aware that AI-generated answers are officially banned here.

This answer states what these phrases mean, which is what everyone coming to this page is likely to already know. It does not really engage the question. (This is probably the reason for @tchrist's suspicion that it is AI-generated.) In order to respond to the question, one needs to explain why we do not say naked-handed and bare-eyed.

We also use naked flame, but that is similar to bare feet in that there is no protection.

This seems like an ex post facto rationalization. I doubt there's any such logic in how the terms came to be used.
